# Production IAPs in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

Is it possible to use Production IAP's with a TestFlight build of an app? The idea here is to allow people to make real IAP's but as part of a beta.

Most of the references I see to TestFlight mention Sandbox IAPs only.

Comment: Unclear what the question is? There is no such thing as a sandbox IAP; an IAP is real. Do you mean the _account_ that you purchase with? In TestFlight testing, you use your real AppleID account, not a Sandbox account.

Comment: @matt the documentation specifies that TestFlight IAPs are Sandboxed IAPs and are all free. It doesn't look like there's a way to use "real" production IAPs in TestFlight as far as I can tell.

Comment: If real means you literally want to spend real money by buying the purchase with your real account, no there isn’t. But why would you ever ever want that??? Your testers would be furious.

Comment: @matt it's becoming more common to run private betas that are "live" to build up a community before a public launch. There's even an "App Store for TestFlights" that was recently released to the App Store. Guess it's not possible to deal with IAPs though.

Comment: If you have a good use case, file this as an enhancement suggestion with Apple! Obviously they _could_ give you a way to switch on "reality", so explain to them why they should do that.

Comment: @matt good idea. thanks!